# Laravel live editing

Tags: php, laravel, sockets

I'm developing a text editor web application which allows the users to collaboratively work on a file at once similar to how Codeshare.io works. 
I understand that I need to use sockets to connect the multiple users to the session, but how should I save the data so that all the content is available when a new user logs into the session. As well as keeping it available when no users are currently accessing it.

I'm currently using Laravel to develop this site.

Comment: Have you tried some code yet?

Comment: No, I have no idea where to start. Im asking for suggestions or a push in the right direction.

Comment: IMHO, no need to save every time the editor changes. You can set the duration for each user to save it as a draft or original data. For example, when you try to write a new email in Gmail, every time you type and then pause, the system will be saved as a draft.

Comment: You ca begin with: https://pusher.com/tutorials/collaborative-note-app-laravel/ this may help you draw the right inspiration

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io, which is most likely the socket based system you would want to use, has a demo [Here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/whiteboard)